# A way to mark things in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, brackets

I want to mark the weight function in an equation, using something similar to `\underbrace`. Using this piece of code:

```
(x^2y')' + \lambda \underbrace{x^2}_{\text{Weight function}}y = 0
```

I get

[image: equation].

I don't want such a big space between the `x²` and the other parts of the equation. I wouldn't mind, for example, having an arrow leading downwards, and there to write the description. Is there any way to do what I describe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I've played around with different ways of highlighting `x²` without resorting to any (major) additional packages. There are ways of doing it more elegantly (using [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), for example):

[image: Different ways of highlight math elements]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{grahpicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  (x^2y')' + \lambda \underbrace{x^2}_{\text{\makebox[0pt]{Weight function}}}y = 0
\]

\[
  (x^2y')' + \lambda \mathop{\rlap{\resizebox{1em}{\ht\strutbox}{$\underbrace{\phantom{x^2}}$}}x^2}_{\text{\makebox[0pt]{Weight function}}}y = 0
\]

\[
  (x^2y')' + \lambda
  \begin{array}[t]{@{\,}c@{\,}}
    x^2 \\ \downarrow \\ \makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize Weight function}
  \end{array}
  y = 0 
\]

\[
  (x^2y')' + \lambda
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}
    \fbox{$x^2$} \\ \downarrow \\ \makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize Weight function}
  \end{array}
  y = 0 
\]

\[
  (x^2y')' + \lambda \underset{\text{\makebox[0pt]{Weight function}}}{\underset{\downarrow}{x^2}}  y = 0 
\]
\end{document}
```

Option 1 is fairly basic. Option 2 sets a fake `x²` with a appropriate `\underbrace`, but resizes it to the width of `1em`, before typesetting the rest of the expression as `\mathop`. Options 3 & 4 use an `array` to stack symbols. Option 5 uses a stacked-`\underset`.

Comment: Thanks! It's weird that we have to use an array to do such a basic thing. Do you think it is possible to combine the first and last one, i.e. do that brace and the arrow?

Comment: @Hugo: I've added a "resized `\underbrace`" option. I don't think it would look good to have an `\underbrace` and a `\downarrow`, since they both are arrow-like.

Answer (score 6):

The `mathtools` package gives the command `\mathclap`, which can be used to give

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
    (x^2y')' + \lambda \underbrace{x^2}_{\mathclap{\text{Weight function}}}y = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. That does narrow the gap, but still isn't quite what I wanted.

Comment: I find this to be the cleanest solution of all the offered ones.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way:

```
\let\hw\hidewidth
$$
  (x^2y')'+\lambda \underbrace{\mathop{x^2}}_{\hw\fam0 Weight~function\hw} y = 0
$$
\bye
```

[image]