# How can I add an explanation under an equal sign in Lyx (/Tex)?

Tags: equations, lyx

When I write some equation with pen and paper I usually do something
like in the following picture:
[image]

Is there a way to do something similar in Lyx (my working environment)
/Tex ? That is: having an arrow or something like that that refers
to the $=$ sign and have some (short) text near

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using an underbrace or the like might do what you want. To prevent the text in the underbrace from affecting the spacing of your equation, you could use `\mathclap`, which is not currently supported in LyX 2.0.x. It will be supported in LyX 2.1 though and instructions are below. If you use Ubuntu, there is a PPA for LyX 2.1 that makes it very easy to install. Ask if you would like instructions.

1. Add the underbrace:
   [image]
2. Press the right arrow once so that you are just to the right of the underbrace.
3. Enter a subscript (in cua binding it is the underscore).
4. Enter "\mathclap" and press space or "{" after the p. You will see an empty red box show up with two arrows pointing at each other.
5. Press "ctrl+m" to make a text box.
6. Enter your text.

[image]

If you want, select the other math inset and go to Insert > Preview. If you have preview turned on in the preferences, you will get:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the detailed explanation. It helped me very much... Just a small question - why is the Text Box needed? I did it without it, and it looks OK (I think...)

Comment: @Zvika it is a choice. I suppose I recommended the text box because the explanation is text, not math. I think that if you use math to format the explanation, then it might not have correct spacing. If you like the italics that math gives, perhaps use italics in text mode? Then again, if you like the formatting of math, then go for it.

Answer (score 12):

For very short things (without arrow) you could use the `\underset` (or `\stackrel`) command. For more fancy annotations you could mix equations with tikz, as shown here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/ see also https://sites.google.com/site/kaarebmikkelsen/in-the-news/fancyequationsinlatexbeamerwithtikz

To provide a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article} %

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc}


\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\everymath{\displaystyle}

Using tikz:

\begin{equation*}
   x
   \tikz[baseline=-1pt]{
     \node (eq)
     {$=$};
   }
   y
\end{equation*}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
   \node (t) at ($(eq) + (-0.5,-0.5)$) {\footnotesize Explanation};
   \path[->,shorten >= 6pt] (eq.base) edge [bend left=10] (t.mid) ;
\end{tikzpicture}


Using underset:

\begin{equation*}
   x \underset{\mathrm{def}}{=} y
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image: output]

Comment: Nice. And for many other LaTeX solutions like this, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42613/a-way-to-mark-things-in-math-mode

Answer (score 7):

This is rather an improvement of [students answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79822/115883). You can combine underset or overset with TikZ and lapping. Look at this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  x
  % with tikzpicture environment
  \underset{\mathllap{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) to[bend right=20] ++(0.3,2ex);
      \node[below left] at (0,0) {because $x = y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }}{=}
  y + x - x
  % with tikz command
  \overset{\mathclap{\tikz \node {$\downarrow$} node [above=1ex] {trivial};}}{=}
  y + y - y
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: LaTeX output as picture showing formula and reasoning]